# Future get() gets nullpointer exeception in java

Tags: swing, nullpointerexception, executorservice, future, javacv

I'm implementing a function that detects if there is a webcam. This piece of code works fine in windows and I had no problem with it in linux centos OS. Now I'm trying to run the same code in Ubuntu, here an exception is thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at CameraProperties.CheckForCameraPlugin.check(CheckForCameraPlugin.java:51)
at Main.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

The code is given below.

```
public boolean check() 
{ 
    boolean b = true;
    service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    task = service.submit(new InitialCameraChecker());
    try 
    {
        final String str;
        // waits the 10 seconds for the Callable.call to finish.
        str = task.get();
        if (str.matches("nodevice"))
        {
            b = false;//Return false if no camera device found
        } 
        else 
        {
            b = true;
        }

    } 
    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) 
    {            
        msgbox.showJoptionPane(15);
    }
    service.shutdownNow();
    return b;
}
```

The callable class is given below

```
class InitialCameraChecker implements Callable<String>
{
private List<Integer> devices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private final static String VERSION_ID = "1.0.0";
private String res;

//Checking for the Camera 
public String call() 
{
    try 
    {
        loadWebcam();
        discoverDevices();
        if (devices.isEmpty()) 
        {                
            res = "nodevice";//No we cam device found
        } 
        else 
        {                
            res = "founddevice";//Found Web Cam Device
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception_logout" + ex.toString());
    }
    return res;
}


//Discovering the camera device
private void discoverDevices() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        CvCapture cap = null;
        try 
        {
            cap = cvCreateCameraCapture(i);
            int res = cvGrabFrame(cap);
            if (res > 0) 
            {
                devices.add(i);                    
                break;
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Exception in camaracheck Thread1");
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (cap != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    cvReleaseCapture(cap.pointerByReference());
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//Loading the dlls for starting the camera
private void loadWebcam() 
{    
    String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");        
    File faPath = new File(tmpDir + File.separator + "WebcamApplet_" + VERSION_ID.replaceAll("\\.", "-"));        
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path", faPath.getAbsolutePath());
}
}
```

Please tell me what is the problem. This works fine in windows.

Comment: What I see in your code is, the place where you can get this error is when you compare the result string with "nodevice", as you are not checking if the string is null or not. And the chances that your callable class returns null is you get an error in `loadWebcam()` or `discoverDevices()` methods. This is just a guess but might help you get started. ;)

Comment: I found that the problem is with discoverDevices(), I convetrted it to boolean and retuned the value nothing wass gettin printed.

Comment: in discoverdevices() the cap = cvCreateCameraCapture(i); statement is creating the problem.

Comment: That is all good but the fact is that this is working in windows fine and it is not working in linux

Comment: Is there any steps I should take for installation of javacv similar to the installation of JMyron.